# What is the 'correct' way localize programmatically created strings in Swift/Xcode?

Tags: swift, localization

From what I understand, localizing Storyboard objects is fairly straightforward: you have a file that looks something like this:

```
/* Class = "NSMenuItem"; title = "Superscript"; ObjectID = "Rqc-34-cIF"; */
"Rqc-34-cIF.title" = "Superscript";

/* Class = "NSMenuItem"; title = "Select All"; ObjectID = "Ruw-6m-B2m"; */
"Ruw-6m-B2m.title" = "Select All";

/* Class = "NSTextFieldCell"; placeholderString = "0"; ObjectID = "RxW-oS-gX3"; */
"RxW-oS-gX3.placeholderString" = "0";

/* Class = "NSTextFieldCell"; title = "0"; ObjectID = "RxW-oS-gX3"; */
"RxW-oS-gX3.title" = "0";

/* Class = "NSMenuItem"; title = "Jump to Selection"; ObjectID = "S0p-oC-mLd"; */
"S0p-oC-mLd.title" = "Jump to Selection";

/* Class = "NSButtonCell"; title = "Play"; ObjectID = "qjC-b0-dMe"; */
"qjC-b0-dMe.title" = "Play";
```

and to localize each string, you just replace the text on the right with its localized equivalent. Easy enough.

However, what if the code is displaying a label or dialog box, where the string is defined in the code? For example:

```
if (dialogOKCancel("Invalid Path", text: "The file/path you selected does not exist, is not a valid sound file, or cannot be accessed by the program.")) {
    self.dismissController(self)
}
```

or

```
let result = dialogOKCancel("Discard Changes?", text: "Press Cancel to close this window and save your changes to \(filename), or OK to create a new file.")
```

I know there are a number of different ways I could do it (defining strings at startup according to localization settings detected by the app was one thing I thought of), but I'm wondering if there's a 'correct'/official way to do what I'm trying to accomplish, or if not, what the best/most efficient method is.

Comment: My understanding is that [`NSLocalizedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedString) is the idiomatic way to handle this. [Here’s another article](http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/) I found about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old Objective C way of accessing it was:

```
NSString *name = "Craig";
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Hello %@", nil),name];
```

The Swift version looks like:

```
let name = "Craig"
let msg = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Hello %@", comment: ""), name)
```